# How compute some arithmetical operation on every row in CSV file

Tags: csv, arithmetic-expressions

I starting with python and i have one question about CSV file where I have rows with data in format number;number:

- 485;16
- 646;8
- 920;16
- 1102;36

My code know how import csv, but I dont know how I can do some  arithmetical operation on every row, f.e. multiplication, division etc. and save it in some variable.

```
import csv

with open('in.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify delimiter correctly: `delimiter=';'`

Then you can access elements by `row[0]` and `row[1]`, but they are strings.

So you have to convert them into integer `int(row[0])`

All together:

```
import csv
with open('in.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in spamreader:
        some_variable = int(row[0])*int(row[1])
        print(some_variable)
```